# cannot convert to a pointer type socket programming in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pointers

I am a beginner with sockets in C and trying to develop my first application 
this is a portion of the client code and it is giving me an error
the error is caused by the line indicated below.

```
    int sockfd = 0;  

char fromServer[MAXSIZE];

char * fromClient;

fromClient=(char*)malloc(MAXSIZE * sizeof(char));



struct sockaddr_in  remoteServAddr;
    sockfd  = Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   }
   int n;

   printf(">>");

   scanf("%s",&fromClient); //the error is on this line 

   sendto(sockfd,fromClient,MAXSIZE,0,(SA*)remoteServAddr,sizeof(remoteServAddr));
```

UPDATE: 
the error is fixed thank you

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: its "cannot convert to a pointer type"

Comment: Are there any other warnings issued by the conpiler?

Comment: Fix those and most probably the error also will be gone.

Comment: You might like to accept the answer that solved your problem, by clicking the answer's check-mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char * fromClient;

fromClient=(char*)malloc(MAXSIZE * sizeof(char))
/* no need to cast, check the result, and sizeof(char) is always 1 */
...
scanf("%s",&fromClient);
/* scanf expects a pointer and fromClient is already a pointer */
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", fromClient);
```

Anyway, use `fgets` to prevent buffer overflows:

```
char *fromClient, *pos;

fgets(fromClient, MAXSIZE, stdin);
if ((pos = strchr(fromClient, '\n')) != NULL)
    *pos = '\0';
```

**EDIT** (as suggested by @egur):

And in `sendto`:

> **dest_addr:**
>       Points to a sockaddr structure containing the destination address. The length and format of the address depend on the address family of
>   the socket.

```
(SA*)remoteServAddr
```

should be

```
(SA*)&remoteServAddr
```

(assuming that `SA` is an alias for `struct sockaddr`)

Comment: @user3108337 Are you sure?

Comment: @Alter Mann this is how it looks now ===> 
char * fromClient;

fromClient= malloc(MAXSIZE);
fgets(fromClient, MAXSIZE, stdin);

yes I am 
31:41: error: cannot convert to a pointer type

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s",&fromClient);
```

-->

```
scanf("%s", fromClient); // fromClient is already a char*
```

Comment: char * fromClient;

 fromClient= malloc(MAXSIZE);
        scanf("%s", fromClient); 

this still gives the same error